# Android Default Notification sound not working

Tags: android, android-notifications

I can see on MI phone android version 10. i am trying to create a simple notification with title and subtitle. notification also shows up but with no sound and no vibration.

PFB the code:

```
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        
                String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                                .setContentTitle(title)
                                .setContentText(messageBody)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_white);
                    notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
                } else {
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_white);
                }
        
        
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        
                // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                            "Channel human readable title",
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    CharSequence name = getResources().getString(R.string.feroz_channel_name);
                    String description = getResources().getString(R.string.feroz_channel_description);
                    channel.enableLights(true);
                    channel.setLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
                    channel.enableVibration(true);
                    channel.setDescription(description);
        
        
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
        
                notificationManager.notify(77 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I have vibration permission in Android Manifest. Along with no sound and no vibration. this notification is not visible when device is in locked state. Please suggest what i have missed in the code to achieve this scenario on android 10.

[image: Mi Phone]

Comment: For updating the importance level programmatically, we must uninstall the program first and then reinstall it.